# Additional configuration for HDFS cluster in Apache Beam

Tags: hdfs, apache-beam

Does anyone know if there is a way to specify additional xml configuration files for HDFS in Apache Beam?
As I see it has two options:

1. hdfsConfiguration property in startup command.
2. core-site.xml and hdfs-site.xml files which are loaded by
   [HadoopFileSystemOptions#ConfigurationLocator](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.5.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/hdfs/HadoopFileSystemOptions.html) if the first option is not specified

Maybe there is something else what I'm missing what can allows to specify some other files?

Comment: Can you explain what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to create different config for one specific job, place it in xml file and load somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem with such approach:

```
    PipelineOptions po = ???
    List<Configuration> configs = ???
    HadoopFileSystemOptions options = po.as(HadoopFileSystemOptions.class);
    options.setHdfsConfiguration(configs);
    org.apache.beam.sdk.io.FileSystems.setDefaultPipelineOptions(options);
```